# Change Default kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am using ipython 6.4.0 on ubuntu 20.04 and using `jupyter kernelspec list` , I found, there are 2 kernels :

1. practice_applied_ai
2. python3

When I open any .ipynb file, it directly opens in "python3" but I want to open it in "practice_applied_ai" because I created virtual environment practice_applied_ai and only in this kernel I can import Tensorflow 2.2.0 for my work.
My question is, Is there any way to change my default kernel without removing any kernel ?

Comment: I have the same issue. What I found and tried was the following: setting the following in the jupyter_notebook_config.py, but this seems to be ignored when opening new notebooks:

cMultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name = 'own_kernel'

Answer (score 15):

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

open the generated config file change
change this line to your desired kernel

```
#c.MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name = 'python3'
```

like

```
c.MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name = 'py38'
```

Comment: In the config file, MultiKernelManager comes before MappingKernelManager, so, this is a better answer!

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me. It keeps reverting back to the original.

Answer (score 8):

See this answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3338#issuecomment-668168649).
As explained there:

> the default kernel name is rarely used. It really only comes into play when a request is received to start a kernel and the kernel name is not specified in the request payload. Since both Notebook and Lab UIs essentially require the user to select a kernel (for new notebooks), it doesn't really come into play.

Put `c.MappingKernelManager.default_kernel_name='newDefault'` in [config file](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).

> To confirm the default is in place, hit the kernelspecs REST API of your running notebook server (e.g., http://localhost:8888/api/kernelspecs) and you should see the default kernel name as the first entry in the returned payload.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on visiting http://localhost:8888/api/kernelspecs. Great sanity check

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible via the `.ipynb` file itself.
Set the following variables in the metadata, specifically the `name` which identifies the kernel

```
  "metadata": {
   "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3 (PyTorch 1.6 Python 3.6 CPU Optimized)",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3__SAGEMAKER_INTERNAL__arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:081325390199:image/pytorch-1.6-cpu-py36-ubuntu16.04-v1"
   },
   "language_info": {
    "codemirror_mode": {
```