# How can I select a kernel automatically in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

Every time I start jupyter-lab, it asks me to select a kernel and that's a problem. I would like to set or select a default kernel automatically. How can I do that? I am using JupyterLab 3.4 on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780291/7789963

Comment: @medium-dimensional No, it didn't work. I also tried other answers in that thread.

Comment: This is not an expected behaviour, maybe a bug in a specific environment?