# Setting my Virtual Environment as default when launching Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I run a couple of Jupyter notebooks in my C# GUI application that always boots to a single default kernel. Some of those notebooks are also running in AppMode which needs to run in the virtual environment I created. Right now I have to manually select the kernel from a dropdown to have the kernel that I want which is not really possible when running the notebooks in AppMode ([AppMode Gitub](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode))

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow boot Jupyter with the kernel that I want without wondering if I have the right kernel?

I tried all of the solutions posted here but they seem to not pick the kernel that I have for some reason even when it's available within the dropdown menu: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709500/change-default-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook#:~:text=Put%20c.,entry%20in%20the%20returned%20payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709500/change-default-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook#:%7E:text=Put%20c.,entry%20in%20the%20returned%20payload) and manually changing .ipynb files for 100s of .ipynb scripts is a hassle that I wouldn't really like to undertake.