# Change Default kernel in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

Using jupyter kernelspec list, I found, there are 2 kernels:

dataanalysis
python3

When I open any .ipynb file, it directly opens in "python3" but I want to open it in "analysis" because I created a virtual environment dataanalysis and only in this kernel I imported all necessary packages

My question is, Is there any way to change my default kernel without removing any kernel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709500/change-default-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook is a duplicate, not sure the solutions there actually work (some comments suggest they don't) but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2759

The solution is to rename the folder of the kernel you would like to use to `python3`(base kernel)
Use the `jupyter kernelspec list` command to find the kernel